# SceneKit – Rotate and animate a SCNNode

Tags: swift, animation, 3d, scenekit

I'm trying to display a pyramid that points following the z axis and then rotates on itself around z too.
As my camera is on the z axis, I'm expecting to see the pyramid from above. I managed to rotate the pyramid to see it this way but when I add the animation it seems to rotate on multiple axis.

Here is my code:

```
// The following create the pyramid and place it how I want
let pyramid = SCNPyramid(width: 1.0, height: 1.0, length: 1.0)
let pyramidNode = SCNNode(geometry: pyramid)
pyramidNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
pyramidNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: Float(M_PI / 2))
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(pyramidNode)

// But the animation seems to rotate aroun 2 axis and not just z
var spin = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "rotation")
spin.byValue = NSValue(SCNVector4: SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: 2*Float(M_PI)))
spin.duration = 3
spin.repeatCount = HUGE
pyramidNode.addAnimation(spin, forKey: "spin around")
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Trying to both manually set and animate the same property can cause issues. Using a `byValue` animation makes the problem worse -- that concatenates to the current transform, so it's harder to keep track of whether the current transform is what the animation expects to start with.

Instead, separate the fixed orientation of the pyramid (its apex is in the -z direction) from the animation (it spins around the axis it points in). There's two good ways to do this:

1. Make `pyramidNode` the child of another node that gets the one-time rotation (π/2 around x-axis), and apply the spin animation directly to `pyramidNode`. (In this case, the apex of the pyramid will still point in the +y direction of its local space, so you'll want to spin around that axis instead of the z-axis.)
2. Use the `pivot` property to transform the local space of `pyramidNode`'s contents, and animate `pyramidNode` relative to its containing space.

Here's some code to show the second approach:

```
let pyramid = SCNPyramid(width: 1.0, height: 1.0, length: 1.0)
let pyramidNode = SCNNode(geometry: pyramid)
pyramidNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
// Point the pyramid in the -z direction
pyramidNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2), 1, 0, 0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(pyramidNode)

let spin = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "rotation")
// Use from-to to explicitly make a full rotation around z
spin.fromValue = NSValue(SCNVector4: SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: 0))
spin.toValue = NSValue(SCNVector4: SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: CGFloat(2 * M_PI)))
spin.duration = 3
spin.repeatCount = .infinity
pyramidNode.addAnimation(spin, forKey: "spin around")
```

Some unrelated changes to improve code quality:

- Use `CGFloat` when explicit conversion is required to initialize an `SCNVector` component; using `Float` or `Double` specifically will break on 32 or 64 bit architecture.
- Use `.infinity` instead of the legacy BSD math constant `HUGE`. This type-infers to whatever the type of `spin.repeatCount` is, and uses a constant value that's defined for all floating-point types.
- Use `M_PI_2` for π/2 to be pedantic about precision.
- Use `let` instead of `var` for the animation, since we never assign a different value to `spin`.

---

More on the `CGFloat` error business: In Swift, numeric literals have no type until the expression they're in needs one. That's why you can do things like `spin.duration = 3` -- even though `duration` is a floating-point value, Swift lets you pass an "integer literal". But if you do `let d = 3; spin.duration = d` you get an error. Why? Because variables/constants have explicit types, and Swift doesn't do implicit type conversion. The `3` is typeless, but when it gets assigned to `d`, type inference defaults to choosing `Int` because you haven't specified anything else.

If you're seeing type conversion errors, you probably have code that mixes literals, constants, and/or values returned from functions. You can probably just make the errors go away by converting everything in the expression to `CGFloat` (or whatever the type you're passing that expression to is). Of course, that'll make your code unreadable and ugly, so once you get it working you might start removing conversions one at a time until you find the one that does the job.

Comment: Thanks rickster, that's exactly what I was looking for. One more thing regarding the use of CGFloat. I started to use them but xcode through a compile error "'Int' is not convertible to 'Float'" hence I've changed them to Float. Any ideas why?

Comment: Wow!  Great job rickster using my edited answer. Check the time stamps!

Comment: See edited answer for more about `CGFloat` conversion issues. @FlippinFun: I didn't see your edited answer. :) It took me more than 8 minutes to make sure mine addressed the "orientation different from rotation axis" issue and otherwise clean up and test the code.

Comment: @rickster. Thats ok. Your answer is better 

Comment: Thanks rickster but I think the problem I have with CGFloat is related to SCNMatrix4MakeRotation taking Floats as parameters instead of CGFloats. I don't understand why because I have seen many examples using CGFloat for this function. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCNMatrix4MakeRotation

Comment: Ah, yes — some of the SCN structs use `CGFloat` and some use just `Float`. The examples you saw probably predate whichever beta it was where `CGFloat` became its own distinct type.

Comment: @rickster Can you answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447924/camera-is-not-following-the-airplane-in-scenekit

Answer (score 15):

SceneKit includes animation helpers which are much simpler & shorter to use than CAAnimations. This is ObjC but gets across the point:

```
[pyramidNode runAction:
    [SCNAction repeatActionForever:
        [SCNAction rotateByX:0 y:0 z:2*M_PI duration:3]]];
```

Comment: Actions aren't shortcuts for animations per se — they take effect in a different part of SceneKit's rendering architecture. Sometimes this difference is important, so you can't *always* use actions and animations interchangeably. But if it doesn't make a difference to your app, go right ahead. :)

Comment: @rickster is there anywhere to read up more on the difference? I'm now unsure when I should use one vs the other.

Comment: The [SceneKit talk from WWDC 2014](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-609/) Tallis a good start. Otherwise it's too big a subject for a comment, but it'd make a good question.

Answer (score 0):

I changed byValue to toValue and this worked for me. So change the line...

```
spin.byValue = NSValue(SCNVector4: SCNVector4(...
```

Change it to...

```
spin.toValue = NSValue(SCNVector4: SCNVector4(x: 0, y:0, z:1, w: 2*float(M_PI))
```

Comment: That line is a call to the `NSValue` initializer `init(SCNVector4 v: SCNVector4)`. Your change doesn't compile.

Comment: Swift requires labels for all initializer parameters, unless the declaration of the initializer specifies `_` as the label. `NSValue` doesn't declare `init(_ v: SCNVector4)`.

Comment: You are right rickster. I got it to work with toValue. I changed my answer.