# Camera is not following the airplane in Scenekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, scenekit

I have a flying aircraft which I am following and I am also showing the path the aircraft has followed. I am drawing cylinders as a line for drawing the path. Its kind of drawing a line between 2 points. I have a cameraNode which is set to (0,200,200) initially. At that point I can see the aircraft. But when I start my flight. It goes out of the screen. I want 2 things :

1. Follow just the aircraft (Path won't matter).
2. Show whole path and also the aircraft.

I tried finding the min ad max x,y and z and taking average but it din't work. If you see below gif its too zoomed and aircraft has moved out of the screen
[image]

Here is how I set my camera:

```
- (void)setUpCamera {
SCNScene *workingScene = [self getWorkingScene];
_cameraNode = [[SCNNode alloc] init];
_cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
_cameraNode.camera.zFar = 500;
_cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 60, 50);
[workingScene.rootNode addChildNode:_cameraNode];

SCNNode *frontCameraNode = [SCNNode node];
frontCameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 100, 50);
frontCameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
frontCameraNode.camera.xFov = 75;
frontCameraNode.camera.zFar = 500;
[_assetActivity addChildNode:frontCameraNode]; //_assetActivity is the aircraft node.
```

}

Here is how I am changing camera position which is not working:

```
- (void)showRealTimeFlightPath {


DAL3DPoint *point = [self.aircraftLocation convertCooridnateTo3DPoint];
DAL3DPoint *previousPoint = [self.previousAircraftLocation convertCooridnateTo3DPoint];
self.minCoordinate = [self.minCoordinate findMinPoint:self.minCoordinate currentPoint:point];
self.maxCoordinate = [self.minCoordinate findMaxPoint:self.maxCoordinate currentPoint:point];
DAL3DPoint *averagePoint = [[DAL3DPoint alloc] init];
averagePoint = [averagePoint averageBetweenCoordiantes:self.minCoordinate maxPoint:self.maxCoordinate];

SCNVector3 positions[] = {
    SCNVector3Make(point.x,point.y,point.z) ,
    SCNVector3Make(previousPoint.x,previousPoint.y,previousPoint.z)
};
SCNScene *workingScene = [self getWorkingScene];
DALLineNode *lineNodeA = [[DALLineNode alloc] init];
[lineNodeA init:workingScene.rootNode v1:positions[0] v2:positions[1] radius:0.1 radSegementCount:6 lineColor:[UIColor greenColor]] ;
[workingScene.rootNode addChildNode:lineNodeA];
self.previousAircraftLocation = [self.aircraftLocation mutableCopy];
self.cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(averagePoint.x, averagePoint.y, z);
self.pointOfView = self.cameraNode;
```

}

Code in swift or objective c are welcomed.

Thanks!!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're asking how to implement two different camera behaviors? Also, can you clarify what you mean by "follow just the aircraft"? Should the camera maintain a minimum distance from the aircraft, or just update to look in its direction?

Comment: @ErikFoss Yes I want 2 behaviors : 1. Follow the aircraft (Camera will just focus on the aircraft not the path). 2. Show the whole path travelled and the aircraft in just one screen. Camera has to maintain certain distance from aircraft.

Answer (score 7):

The first behavior you describe would most easily be achieved by chaining a look-at constraint and a distance constraint, both targeting the aircraft.

```
let lookAtConstraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: aircraft)

let distanceConstraint = SCNDistanceConstraint(target: aircraft)
distanceConstraint.minimumDistance = 10 // set to whatever minimum distance between the camera and aircraft you'd like
distanceConstraint.maximumDistance = 10 // set to whatever maximum distance between the camera and aircraft you'd like

camera.constraints = [lookAtConstraint, distanceConstraint]
```

For iOS 10 and earlier, you can implement a distance constraint using `SCNTransformConstraint`. Here's a basic (though slightly ugly ) implementation that uses linear interpolation to update the node's position.

```
func normalize(_ value: Float, in range: ClosedRange<Float>) -> Float {
    return (value - range.lowerBound) / (range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)
}

func interpolate(from start: Float, to end: Float, alpha: Float) -> Float {
    return (1 - alpha) * start + alpha * end
}

let target = airplane

let minimumDistance: Float = 10
let maximumDistance: Float = 15

let distanceConstraint = SCNTransformConstraint(inWorldSpace: false) { (node, transform) -> SCNMatrix4 in
    let distance = abs(sqrt(pow(target.position.x - node.position.x, 2) + pow(target.position.y - node.position.y, 2) + pow(target.position.z - node.position.z, 2)))

    let normalizedDistance: Float

    switch distance {
    case ...minimumDistance:
        normalizedDistance = self.normalize(minimumDistance, in: 0 ... distance)
    case maximumDistance...:
        normalizedDistance = self.normalize(maximumDistance, in: 0 ... distance)
    default:
        return transform
    }

    node.position.x = self.interpolate(from: target.position.x, to: node.position.x, alpha: normalizedDistance)
    node.position.y = self.interpolate(from: target.position.y, to: node.position.y, alpha: normalizedDistance)
    node.position.z = self.interpolate(from: target.position.z, to: node.position.z, alpha: normalizedDistance)

    return transform
}
```

The second behavior could be implemented by determining the bounding box of your aircraft and all of its path segments in the camera's local coordinate space, then updating the camera's distance from the center of that bounding box to frame all of those nodes in the viewport. `frameNodes(_:)`, a convenience method that implements this functionality, was introduced in iOS 11 and is defined on `SCNCameraController`. I'd recommend using it if possible, unless you want to dive into the trigonometry yourself. You could use your scene view's default camera controller or create a temporary instance, whichever suits the needs of your app.

Comment: Bounding box means finding max and min x,y,z and finding the average? Also, can you give an example code how to use frameNodes.

Comment: Well, I don't know how you're storing the nodes you want to frame, so I can't write that part for you. The first thing you'll need to do is get those in an array. Then retrieve or create a camera controller; if you're not using your scene view's default camera controller, simply create a new instance (`let cameraController = SCNCameraController()`) and assign the current point of view (`cameraController.pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView`). Then call `frameNodes(_:)`, passing your array (`cameraController.frameNodes(nodes)`). That should be all you need to do!

Comment: By "bounding box", I mean the rectangular volume that encloses all your nodes. The center of that bounding box is the point to move toward or away from to reach the target distance for framing the nodes.

Comment: All these methods are in ios 11 beta. They don't work for xcode 8.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have assumed you were using the betas. A distance constraint can be implemented using `SCNTransformConstraint` pretty easily, and `SCNLookAtConstraint` is available in iOS 8 and later. I could edit my post with an example of those if you'd like.

Comment: It will be great if you can Edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the angle of the velocity so that the camera points in the direction of the moving SCNNode.

This code will point you in the right direction.

```
    func renderer(_ aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

        // get velocity angle using velocity of vehicle

        var degrees = convertVectorToAngle(vector: vehicle.chassisBody.velocity)

        // get rotation of current camera on X and Z axis

        let eX = cameraNode.eulerAngles.x
        let eZ = cameraNode.eulerAngles.z

        // offset rotation on y axis by 90 degrees

        // this needs work, buggy

        let ninety = deg2rad(90)

        // default camera Y Euler angle facing north at 0 degrees

        var eY : Float = 0.0

        if degrees != 0 {

            eY = Float(-degrees) - Float(ninety)

        }

        // rotate camera direction using cameraNode.eulerAngles and direction of velocity as eY

        cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(eX, eY, eZ)

        // put camera 25 points behind vehicle facing direction of velocity

        let dir = calculateCameraDirection(cameraNode: vehicleNode)
        let pos = pointInFrontOfPoint(point: vehicleNode.position, direction:dir, distance: 25)

        // camera follows driver view from 25 points behind, and 10 points above vehicle

        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(pos.x, vehicleNode.position.y + 10, pos.z)

}

func convertVectorToAngle(vector: SCNVector3) -> CGFloat {

    let degrees = atan2(vector.z, vector.x)

    return CGFloat(degrees)

}


func pointInFrontOfPoint(point: SCNVector3, direction: SCNVector3, distance: Float) -> SCNVector3 {

    var x = Float()
    var y = Float()
    var z = Float()

    x = point.x + distance * direction.x
    y = point.y + distance * direction.y
    z = point.z + distance * direction.z

    let result = SCNVector3Make(x, y, z)
    return result

}

func calculateCameraDirection(cameraNode: SCNNode) -> SCNVector3 {

            let x = -cameraNode.rotation.x
            let y = -cameraNode.rotation.y
            let z = -cameraNode.rotation.z
            let w = cameraNode.rotation.w
            let cameraRotationMatrix = GLKMatrix3Make(cos(w) + pow(x, 2) * (1 - cos(w)),
                                                      x * y * (1 - cos(w)) - z * sin(w),
                                                      x * z * (1 - cos(w)) + y*sin(w),

                                                      y*x*(1-cos(w)) + z*sin(w),
                                                      cos(w) + pow(y, 2) * (1 - cos(w)),
                                                      y*z*(1-cos(w)) - x*sin(w),

                                                      z*x*(1 - cos(w)) - y*sin(w),
                                                      z*y*(1 - cos(w)) + x*sin(w),
                                                      cos(w) + pow(z, 2) * ( 1 - cos(w)))

            let cameraDirection = GLKMatrix3MultiplyVector3(cameraRotationMatrix, GLKVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, -1.0))
            return SCNVector3FromGLKVector3(cameraDirection)
}

func deg2rad(_ number: Double) -> Double {

        return number * .pi / 180

}
```