# Implicitly animating SCNNode's transition from one ARImageAnchor to another

Tags: swift, animation, scenekit, scnnode

I’m trying to make my AR experience more user friendly.

I have this SCNnode (objectNodeToPlace) that I want to place over the node created/update by the renderers whenever an imageReference is detected by the camera:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
var objectNodeToPlace: SCNNode
...

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
                    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
          placeObject(object: objectNodeToPlace, at: node, ...)
    }
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
                    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
          placeObject(object: objectNodeToPlace, at: node, ...)
    }
}
```

My placeObject function is pretty simple, I’m just changing the orientation of the “objectNodeToPlace”:

```swift
private func placeObject(object objectNodeToPlace: SCNNode, at node: SCNNode, ...) {
    ...
    node.addChildNode(objectNodeToPlace)
}
```

Everything works well, my object is always placed on the latest detected imageReference.

But when my object is place onto an image and a new one is detected, **the object jumps to the newest**, it’s not great, very jittery / jerky.

My goal is to make this transition smoother.

### What I currently have

Here’s what it looks like rigth now:

[What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cquu8.jpg)

In red, the imageReference.

### What I want

Here’s what I would like:

[What I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CoPz.jpg)

### What I’ve found yet

I’ve found this package, [SceneKit Bezier Animations](https://github.com/maxxfrazer/SceneKit-Bezier-Animations), to animate the movement between 2 points but I look a little bit overkill for want I want.

I also read this topic, [SceneKit Rotate and Animate a SCNNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295614/scenekit-rotate-and-animate-a-scnnode), one response suggest to use [CABasicAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cabasicanimation) and another one suggest [SCNAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnaction).

I feel like `SCNAction` is the best way to go for the quick, not that precise animation that I want, I’m not sure of what I’m doing so I will be happy to hear from more experienced developers.

## Edit

I've found what I'm looking for on the Apple documentation [Animating SceneKit Content](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/animation/animating_scenekit_content)
It's called Implicit animation, and it should work with only one line of code that determines the animation duration of my changes :

```swift
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1.0
```

I tried that line just before I change the euler angle (who is "animatable") of my node in my `place()`function:

```swift
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1.0
objectNodeToPlace.eulerAngles.x = radian
```

but that didn't worked. I'm pretty sure that I'm just missing a simple thing but I can't find examples online, even in the documentation of [SCNTransaction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntransaction).

Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Axel,

SCNTransaction needs a minimum of three statements.

```
SCNTransaction.start()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1.0
//commands
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

I written a dozen articles on SceneKit recently you'll find [here](https://medium.com/@marklucking).